# Android, Java, Create directory on SD card programmatically using Storage Access Framework (SAF)

Tags: java, android, directory, filesystems

My problem is that I do not manage to create a directory on a SD card that is plugged in an Android portable device.
Below is the Java code I am trying to get to work: I am trying to create the directory `sable` under `/storage/BF4F-1107/`:

```
public class AnActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private static final int N_CREATE_DIRECTORY = 1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // SD card
        String s_sdCardStorage = "/storage/BF4F-1107/";

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, s_destFilePath);
        startActivityForResult(intent, N_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
        // HERE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == N_CREATE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            if(data != null)
            {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                DocumentFile docFileSDCardStorage = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);

                try
                {
                    DocumentFile docFileDir = docFileSDCardStorage.createDirectory("sable");
                }
                catch(UnsupportedOperationException exn)
                {
                    System.out.println(exn.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is:

- the code in `onCreate()` is executed.
- Then the program blocks at `// HERE`.
- On the portable device, appears a "dialog" which shows `/storage/BF4F-1107/` and a button `Save` which I "press".
- Once "pressed", the code in `onActivityResult()` is executed.

But the result is that the directory `sable` under `/storage/BF4F-1107/` is not created.
And the execution path goes through the catch clause, the exception `UnsupportedOperationException` is raised and **null** is printed at `System.out.println(exn.getMessage());`.

Edit 2: An empty file `_storage_BF4F-1107_` is created under `/storage/BF4F-1107/`.

Can you help me make this code work?

Additionally, I would like the directory `sable` to be created silently.
I do not want to user to have to touch "Save".

I am trying to use the `Storage Access Framework` (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) because the `mkdirs` method of the `java.io.File` class doesn't work (I get permission denied exceptions) when I try to create a directory on the SD card.

Edit: my Android version is 6.0.1

Thank you.

Comment: I edited my post (Edit: and Edit 2:).

Comment: `N_CREATE_DIRECTORY` Your intent created a file with ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT.  Not a directory. What you do in your code is trying to create a directory in a file. That will not work.

Comment: Please edit your post. Remove the old stuff. Post only one problem. Or you let the user choose a folder or you let the user create a file. Your post is very confusing now.

Comment: what i did is to save a meta file in the directory i want to create using SAF ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. this creates the directory (with an empty file like  582020.txt)

Comment: @Angel_Koh Do you mean that you create a file "582020.txt" in "/storage/BF4F-1107/sable/" (for example), that the directory "sable" doesn't exist prior to this operation, and both directory "sable" and file "582020.txt" are created? Can you post a little bit of code? Is your directory silently created? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose de SD card.

After that you can create as many files and directorys in the choosen directory.

If you only want to create one file with SAF use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT where the user chooses the location and file name.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I edited my post. Maybe SAF is not the right framework to use to create a directory under the SD card...

Comment: It is THE way to go but you mixed it all up. So restart please.

Comment: I need the directory to be created silently. Is it possible? This directory is meant to be a "working directory" for my application. That directory will not be erased if the application is uninstalled. My users wont lose their data by inadvertence. Thanks.

Comment: You have to once let the user choose. Thats how its intended to be.

Comment: > This directory is meant to be a "working directory" for my application.

This suggests you should use `Context#getExternalFilesDirs` or `Context#getFilesDir`.

> That directory will not be erased if the application is uninstalled.

That's really up to the user. Look at [`android:hasFragileUserData `](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#fragileuserdata)